# htaccess rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm currently trying to rewrite some URLs, and they all follow a basic format.

Here is the current .htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?d=$1&n=$2 [QSA]
```

Sometimes, there are some links, such as

/users/profiles/userid=2

But, the rule is written to rewrite

/users/profiles

as

index.php?d=users&n=profiles

How can I change the rule so that it can optionally accept and add extra parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule below will rewrite `users/profiles/userid=2` to `index.php?d=users&n=profiles&userid=2`. Tested, working fine.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)=(\d+)$ index.php?d=$1&n=$2&$3=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
```

If you add the above rule above your existing rule they both will play nicely (I have modified your existing rule a bit):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)=(\d+)$ index.php?d=$1&n=$2&$3=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ index.php?d=$1&n=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do not delete your previous rule, just add this one below (or above) -- see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested, but I think this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/(.*)$ index.php?d=$1&n=$2&$3 [QSA]
```

This:

`/users/profiles/userid=2&something=3`

should become like this

`index.php?d=users&n=profiles&userid=2&something=3`

Comment: That kills it, if there is no additional parameter.

Comment: You should combine this rule with the previous rule. @LazyOne has explained you everything :)